# AWS lambda update-function-code: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services

Updating AWS Lambda code from the command line. Using command

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME \
--zip-file fileb://lambdaFunc.zip --publish
```

Returns

```
Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/XX/code"
```

It used to work, and other `aws lambda` commands still work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a networking timeout.

Fix: add `--cli-connect-timeout 6000` to the command line. Eg

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME \
--zip-file fileb://lambdaFunc.zip --cli-connect-timeout 6000 --publish
```

Also, check the size of your zip file: it can't be larger than 50MB. See the [Deployment Package max size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

More info from an [AWS GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3842).

**Please upvote / comment on the feature request to make
`--cli-connect-timeout 6000` be the default:
See the [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5754)**

From CLI help/man page for **--cli-connect-timeout (int)**:

> The maximum socket connect time in seconds. If the value is set to 0,
> the socket connect will be blocking and not timeout. The default value
> is 60 seconds.

Comment: How did you arrive at the number 6,000 (as opposed to 600 or 3,000 or any other number)? And is this milliseconds or seconds? What is the current default?

Comment: (If the answer was useful to you, please upvote it. Thank you.) The cli-connect-timeout setting is in seconds. So 6000 is 100 minutes. You can use whatever value works for you. I don't know the default.